Replacing Objects Fails to Preserve Transformation
I'm trying to replace objects by Linking Object Data. This would be a great example if I could get it to work:
Is there a way to replace an object in my scene with a different one?
My problem is that the objects are replaced by the 'Master' object, but their transformation also matches the master. So all of these newly replaced objects are stacked on top of one another.
How do I maintain each objects' original transformation while just replacing the geometry?
I get the same result in Blender 2.92, 3.6, 4.0, and 4.1.
Note: The objects I want to replace were created by geometry nodes. I have made these instances 'real'. I have also tried to apply all transforms. I also tried to clear location. Nothing seems to work. If I open up a new project and add/copy cubes and then add a sphere, the replace works as expected.
Edit: These objects, I can change their locations by moving the origin to World-Origin/Cursor or Geo. But their Rotation and Scale is all default. How can I preserve the actual transformations when converting from GNs?

One problem seems to be with the objects' origin. Each object had its' origin at 000. Changing the origins to geo allowed for replacement. But the newly replaced objects kept the master's scale and rotation.

Can you share a blend file with the original object and the object you want as replacement?

So did I get this correctly that the objects you want to replace are created with geometry nodes...? They were instances which you made real and then applied the GN modifier? But those are then just like separate meshes within a single object. A single object only has one rotation and scale, the geometry within has no separate transformation on its own. Let's say you have the default cube mesh. If you duplicate the cube in Edit Mode and rotate it, this new mesh will inherit the rotation information of the object it is part of, not keep the values you used to rotate it.

@HarryMcKenzie I would rather not share as it is proprietary at this point. However, it's fairly easy to repro. I created a tree using the mTree plugin (Steven-Ray fork). https://github.com/steven-ray/modular_tree/releases The 'Twig' was replaced with an 8-tri plane and the Geo-node modifier was applied so that the tree is all geo. There are two materials -- bark and leaves. I'm just trying to replace each twig-plane with planes of less geo.

@GordonBrinkmann If I dup a cube in Edit mode (then separate to a new object), it's origin remains with the original cube regardless of where I position it. If I dup a cube in Edit mode, but don't separate, it remains a part of the original geo. If I dup a cube in Object mode, it's origin stays with the geo as I reposition it.

@GordonBrinkmann These objects I'm trying to replace are all separate objects. Their origin Locations I can change between World-Origin/Cursor or the Geo. But their Rotations are all 000 and Scales are all 111. I think that may be the problem. When I replace, the new geo is located properly, but rotation and scale are default. Edit above.

@Dev Thanks for the explanations what happens when you duplicate a cube in different variations, but I know all this. It is what I explained to you before. Making duplicates in Geometry Nodes is like doing it in Edit Mode. Even if you separate them, they have no individual transformation data stored somewhere, they inherit the base objects values.
